# stellar core docker address in use

Tags: stellar-core, docker

I am running stellar core docker. When I get into the container and type stellar-core. it gives this error:

```
GAGCM [default INFO] Starting stellar-core v9.2.0
GAGCM [default INFO] Config from stellar-core.cfg
GAGCM [default INFO] Listening on 0.0.0.0:11626 for HTTP requests
GAGCM [default INFO] Application destructing
GAGCM [default INFO] Application destroyed
GAGCM [default FATAL] Got an exception: bind: Address already in use [main.cpp:647]
```

I am not sure what happened here. By default the stellar-core is using port 11625 and 11626, and I have checked that nothing else is bound to that port.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the docker image it should automatically start stellar-core.

In the container, can you try running `ps aux | grep stellar-core | grep -v "grep"` to see if stellar-core is already running?

If you are already running something on port 8000 (i.e. bound to port 8000) on your localhost then it will not work. You can change your command to use a different port on your localhost, something like this: `-p 8001:8000`

Comment: yes i ran the docker image using this command:
sudo docker run -d --rm -it -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet
and yea the stellar core is running. but why it produces that log where the aplication is destroyed?

Comment: maybe you already have something running on your localhost's port 8000?

Comment: no. there is nothing on port 8000. if the stellar core has an error, the horizon should not be able to post transaction to the network right?
in my case, the horizion is still working

Comment: based on your logs it says "Application destroyed" so I assume that your stellar-core node is not running, however in your comment above you said it was running.

Also, if your stellar-core node is down, your horizon instance would still be able to fulfill queries against it using it's own database. Try submitting a transaction via that horizon instance.. if it fails it means that your stellar-core instance is down.